# How to get correct result with JOIN in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I wanted to get badge list with `issued times`.
This is brief info of my tables.

table `Badge`:

```
+----+-----------+
| id |  name     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | professor |
|  2 | campaign  |
|  3 | test      |
+----+-----------+
```

table `issue_history`:

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | badge_id  |   ts   |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 |        1  |  0908  |
|  2 |        1  |  0909  |
|  3 |        3  |  0909  |
+----+-----------+--------*
```

To get result I used `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.name,
    COUNT(*) AS issued_times
FROM
    badge b
LEFT JOIN
    issue_history h
ON
    b.id = h.badge_id
GROUP BY
    b.id
```

I expected result like below

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id |  name     | issued_times |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | professor |            2 |
|  2 | campaign  |            0 |
|  3 | test      |            1 |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

But I got wrong result

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id |  name     | issued_times |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | professor |            2 |
|  2 | campaign  |            1 |
|  3 | test      |            1 |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the issues times of `campaign` badge is **`0`**.
But the result shows its value as **`1`**.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `Count(*)` counts **all the rows** in a particular group. Now, even when you don't have any history row for a specific badge, you you would still have one row for the badge corresponding to the base table `badge`. That is why, you were getting the count as 1.

To count the history rows, you need to `Count()` the `badge_id` from the history table. So if there is no matching row in the history table, `badge_id` on right side table would be `NULL` and `COUNT(NULL) = 0`:

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.name,
    COUNT(h.badge_id) AS issued_times
FROM
    badge b
LEFT JOIN
    issue_history h
ON
    b.id = h.badge_id
GROUP BY
    b.id, 
    b.name
```

Refer this official MySQL document for further understanding: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html

Also, your `GROUP BY` usage was not valid; I added `b.name` in the `GROUP BY` for it to be valid. Check this to get an understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115425/2469308